# Splitting data within a cell [in which JSON format is used] into seperate columns using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Currently working with a dataset that has a cell containing the following information [JSON format] => Column name = "properties".

Below you can see the contents of a single cell within the column:

```
{'gender': 'Female', 'nationality': 'PHL', 'document_type': 'passport', 'date_of_expiry': '2021-05-18', 'issuing_country': 'PHL'}
```

All other cells in the document are single values (often true or false)

I've used the following code to split it up, but due to inconsistencies in the cells (sometimes 'Gender' is missing etc...) it is suboptimal

```
prop = doc["properties"].str.split(",", n = 4, expand = True)

#define
gender=prop[0]
nat=prop[1]
doc=prop[2]
exp=prop[3]
iss=prop[4]

#segment
gender = gender.str.split(":", n = 1, expand = True)
nat = nat.str.split(":", n = 1, expand = True)
doc = doc.str.split(":", n = 1, expand = True)
exp = exp.str.split(":", n = 1, expand = True)
iss = iss.str.split(":", n = 1, expand = True)

#place
df['gender'] = gender[1]
df['nationality'] = nat[1]
df['documentation'] = doc[1]
df['expiry date'] = exp[1]
df['issue country'] = iss[1]

#clean
df['gender'] = df['gender'].str.replace(r' ', '')
df['nationality'] = df['nationality'].str.replace(r' ', '')
df['documentation'] = df['documentation'].str.replace(r' ', '')
df['expiry date'] = df['expiry date'].str.replace(r' ', '')
df['issue country'] = df['issue country'].str.replace(r' ', '')
```

I've found the `pd.json_normalize(data)` finction, but it is also not helpfull to provide an error-free output.

Hope someone can show an answer.

Cheers and much appreciated in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your string to json:

```
import json

jsondata = json.loads(doc["properties"])
```

Use if condition for all of your json items like:

```
df = df.assign(json = lambda x: x["properties"].str.replace("'",'"'))
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    jsondata = json.loads(row["json"])
    if "gender" in jsondata:
        df.loc[i,"gender"] = jsondata["gender"]
    else:
        df.loc[i,"gender"] = np.nan
    ...
    do the same for all other parameters
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223492/discussion-on-answer-by-mhdg7-splitting-data-within-a-cell-in-which-json-format).